# trying to use my custom class constructor without new

Tags: c++

coming from java i would like to not have to deal with de-allocation when creating new custom or other library's objects.

today i was trying to create an instance of my entity object like:

```
entity cube = new entity("entityName")
```

because this is how entity's constructor is formatted
but i get the following error:

```
cannot convert from |entity *| to |entity|
```

i noticed there are no errors if i just remove the `new` keyword, and i was wondering two things.

1. what does the error while using `new` mean ? (i'm pretty confident with how pointers work but not completely as i started with java.)
2. is it ok for me to create objects like that without the `new` keyword or is an object even created? (because there are no errors.)

Comment: What do you mean _custom class constructor_??

Comment: Use `entity *cube = new entity("entityName")`. To understand further, you'll have to read about pointers, local variables and references in C++

Comment: You don't need the `new` syntax unless you are creating a pointer to an object. For the latter case, you must then manually manage the memory by calling `delete` later (or use a smart pointer, but that's a different conversation).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i made a class called entity

Comment: In general, unlike Java, where all except primitives is allocated in the dynamic memory, in C++, you can create class instances on the stack or in the dynamic memory. When you use "new", it means that you allocate dynamic memory, and it returns pointer - hence you have to add a `*` to the variable name. You must read tutorial - can't explain it in a comment and would not like to rewrite good old tutorials

Comment: @SomethingSomething that was actually very informative. i know what pointers are and the stack and heap i was not aware however that i could allocate objects on the stack which i learned about two mins ago

Comment: What prevented you from using capital letters? The word "I" is spelt "I". Not "i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new entity("entityName")
```

means "create an instance of `entity` in the free store and return a pointer to that instance".
Since a pointer to an `entity` is not the same as an `entity`, you cannot initialise an `entity` with that value unless you have yet another constructor.

The way to do what you want is

```
entity cube("entityname");
```

And you need a good book on C++.

Comment: As a both Java and C++ developer, I would also show the case of dynamic allocation. Even though I agree that it's better practice to use the stack, especially to avoid calling `delete`

Answer (score 0):

> 1. what does the error while using new mean ? (i'm pretty confident with how pointers work but not completely as i started with java.)

No. C++ is different about this, you don't use an allocation (new) to initialize `cube`:

```
entity cube("entityName");
```

> 2. is it ok for me to create objects like that without the new keyword or is an object even created? (because there are no errors.)

No. See above. (*"because there are no errors."* I doubt this, there should at least be compiler warnings if you assign `entity` from a pointer.)

Comment: Why would there be a warning for `entity cube = entity("entityName")`?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to read a C++ tutorial. It has much more complexity than Java.

This is a very partial Java to C++ "how to convert" guide that I can give you:

Java code:

```
void sayHello(String name) {
    system.out.println("Hello, " + name);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String name = "James";  //  <-- This string is of course created in the dynamic memory
    sayHello(name);   //  <-- "name" will be passed by reference to the "sayHello()" method
}
```

**Equivalent in C++ - option 1**:

```
void sayHello(const std::string &name) {
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string name("James");  // <-- Variable is created on the stack
    sayHello(name);  // <-- Although "name" is not a pointer, it will be passed by reference to "sayHello", as "name" is defiend there with "&", which means that it is a reference
}
```

A reference is a very "weird" type - it behaves like a local variable, although it actually points to an instance that does not have to be on the stack of the current function or on the stack at all.

**C++ - option 2**:

```
void sayHello(const std::string *name) {
    std::cout << "Hello, " << *name << std::endl;  // <-- dereferenceing "name" using a preceding star, as "cout" needs the variable itself and not its address
}

int main() {
    std::string *name = new std::string("James");  // <-- Instance is created in the dynamic memory
    sayHello(name);  // <-- Sending the pointer "name" to the "sayHello" function
    // You will need to free "name" somewhere in the code unless you don't care about memory leaks
}
```

There are more options, like passing the instance by value (not recommended in such case), or like creating it in the dynamic memory and deref